# How to return a Bool from a Where Filter using Entity Framework and Esql

Tags: entity-sql

I use c# and ef4.

I have a Model with an Entity with two proprieties `int Id` and `string Title`.

I need to write an `ESQL` query that is able to `return bool TRUE` if Id and Title are present in the DataSource. Please note Id is a PrimaryKey in my data storage.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: sorry but is a common situation to check if an ID is present in a DataBase, lets imagine a search from EF to the DataSource for a specific recors.

Comment: Please guys add a comment to your downvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by each code-snippets below:

---

**1)**

```
using (YourEntityContext context = new YourEntityContext ()) {
    var queryString = 
        @"SELECT VALUE TOP(1) Model FROM YourEntityContext.Models 
              As Model WHERE Model.Id = @id AND Model.Title = @title";
    ObjectQuery<Model> entityQuery = new ObjectQuery<Model>(queryString, context);
    entityQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("id", id));
    entityQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("title", title));
    var result = entityQuery.Any();
}
```

---

**2)**

```
using (YourEntityContext context = new YourEntityContext ()) {
    ObjectQuery<Model> entityQuery = 
        context.Models
        .Where("it.Id = @id AND it.Title = @title"
            , new ObjectParameter("id", id)
            , new ObjectParameter("title", title)
        );
    var result = entityQuery.Any();
}
```

---

**3)**

```
var context = new YourEntityContext();
using (EntityConnection cn = context.Connection as EntityConnection) {
    if (cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        cn.Open();
    using (EntityCommand cmd = new EntityCommand()) {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandText = @"EXISTS(
                                SELECT M FROM YourEntityContext.Models as M 
                                WHERE M.Id == @id AND Model.Title = @title
                           )";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", _yourId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", _yourTitle);
        var r = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

---

**4)**

```
using (YourEntityContext context = new YourEntityContext ()) {
    var queryString = 
        @"EXISTS(
              SELECT M FROM YourEntityContext.Models as M 
              WHERE M.Id == @id AND Model.Title = @title
          )";
    ObjectQuery<bool> entityQuery = new ObjectQuery<bool>(queryString, context);
    entityQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("id", id));
    entityQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("title", title));
    var result = entityQuery.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**4** is the best way I suggest you. Good lock

Comment: And you vote me down?!?!?! You tagged your Q by entity-framework. when my answer is correct, how can anybody do it? JS

Comment: thanks J for your message but my questions was about ESQL (sorry if one of my label was wrong), so with your edit I up-vote and accepted your answer. Please consider remove your Down Vote if you have added any to my questions. Thanks for your time.

Comment: OK. and I suggest you in this cases, instead of voting down the answer hurriedly, left a comment to user and wait a moment!!! You are welcome. I'll remove down-vote from your Q and put the easiest way as an update in my A. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

What javad said is true, but another way is:

```
bool result = entities.Any(x=>x.Id == id && x.Title == title) ;
```

In fact because Id is primary key, DB prevent from occurrence of this more than one time .

Comment: Sorry is it in Linq or ESQL? I need in in ESQL.

Comment: @GibboK, This is one of a options when you using EF (in your tags) so IMO you shouldn't downvote correct answer you should clear your question statement by removing tag or saying lin2entity is not allowed, in both case I'll downvote your answer because limiting technology usage is not good in all.

Comment: Saeed Amiri, limiting technology is not an issue here, I need it in ESQL and not linq. Regarding the Tag your are right (was a mistake you could edit anytime), so I will remove the tag. I think is unfair your down vote and not appropriate in this case. Please consider remove your down vote or I consider a flag.

Comment: @GibboK, you should consider flag, because of your mistake i got downvote (from you or another downvoter i don't know), my downvote will be alive until you fix your mistakes.

Comment: Saeed, I understand the situation but my question was stating clearly the ESQL, anyway lets make peace so I will remove my only down vote as soon as possible and i think would be fear if you remove your too, let me know your toughs thanks.

Comment: ok I have removed my down vote on your answer, please do the same. thanks for your help on my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3746/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-gibbok)